# How can we have a close vote that specifies resource gathering as off-topic, yet have a resource-recommendation tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think the title says it all really.

The [resource-recommendations](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) tag is very broad, and could really include anything. We have more specific tags for areas where we're happy to recommend things, but should we really have such an ambiguous tag inviting all kinds of off-topic content?

Doesn't the resource-recommendation tag contradict the resource gathering close reason?

What kinds of resources do we want to recommend, and what kinds of resources do we not want to recommend?

Comment: "Resource gathering" falls under the general "don't ask" help section. The same as "shopping list" questions.

Comment: @Scott I can't actually find that anywhere, do you have a direct link?

Comment: Can't find a direct link either. I know I saw it at some point :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw it somewhere to, might have been in a meta post or even a chat discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't have a close reason that specifies resource gathering as off topic. The text is:

> This looks like **brainstorming/idea gathering** for a specific project or a **request for free work**. This site is suited for answers to general design problems, not ideas or work that is specific to one project. See [this meta post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/183/8708) for more info.

Ideas and resources are very different. We want to discourage idea gathering because of the opinion based nature, which goes directly against the SE model. The linked meta post goes deeper into the reasons for this.

It's possible for a resource gathering question to be outside of our scope, however typically those should be closed as **too broad**. A question along the lines of "*What's a good book on Graphic Design?*" is an example of this. I'm fine with resource recommendation questions that have a specific focus, such as [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/11439/8708).

Comment: I should have checked again.. I think I've made that mistake more than once.